# mediaUpload/uploadedVideo Returns 504 Gateway Timeout frequently

Tags: linkedin-api

When uploading videos to LinkedIn via API we get very frequent 504 timeout errors. We have added in backoff and retry mechanisms, but still get a large percentage of failures due to this. We can manually retry the uploads and eventually they work without changing anything.

Anyone else navigate this issue? Anything we can do with our uploads to reduce or prevent these errors? Some of our upload code below:

```
        data = self.session.post(
            url="/assets",
            params={"action": "registerUpload"},
            json={
                "registerUploadRequest": {
                    "owner": owner,
                    "recipes": ["urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video"],
                    "serviceRelationships": [
                        {"identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent", "relationshipType": "OWNER"}
                    ],
                    "supportedUploadMechanism": ["SYNCHRONOUS_UPLOAD"],
                }
            },
        )
        upload_url = data["value"]["uploadMechanism"][
            "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest"
        ]["uploadUrl"]
        response = self.session.put(
            url=upload_url,
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/binary"},
            data=media.file.open("rb"),
            return_response=True,
        )
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? We are also facing similar problem.

Comment: We are seeing this error too, have not been able to find a workaround yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've been experiencing the same issue and what has worked for us was removing `supportedUploadMechanism` option from the registerUploadRequest.

So the updated JSON should look like the following for you

```
    "registerUploadRequest": {
        "owner": owner,
        "recipes": ["urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video"],
        "serviceRelationships": [
            {"identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent", "relationshipType": "OWNER"}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: This does work. According to the docs and LinkedIn API dev support the SYNCHRONOUS_UPLOAD method is only meant to be used for images

Comment: This works on images as well :)